# Login Issues in CodeIgniter

Tags: php, jquery, codeigniter

I am using PHP Login Script in `COdeigniter` programmed. If i am putting the right credentials in this form, its show an `error`, while after putting the right credentials, if i opened the same form in new tab, its get opened automatically. seems, some js issues. any idea ? here is the `code`

```
 <form method="post" action="#" onsubmit="return validateLogin('loginForm')" name="loginForm"> 
          <table width="100%" cellpadding=0 cellspacing=0>
            <tr>
              <td>
                <b>
                  Username:
                </b> 
              </td>
              <td>
                <input type="text" name="usr" />
              </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>
                <b>
                  Password:
                </b>
              </td>
              <td>
                <input type="password" name="pwd" />
              </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td></td>
              <td>
                <input type="submit" value="Login" class="submit" />
              </td>
            </tr>
          </table>  
        </form>
```

Functions is

```
function validateLogin(form) {
  user = document.forms[form].usr;
  pwd = document.forms[form].pwd;
  if(user.value.length==0)
  {
    notify('Please enter a valid username', 'error');
    user.focus();
    hilit('[name = user]');
    return false;
  }
  else if(pwd.value.length==0)
  {
    notify('Please enter a valid password', 'error');
    pwd.focus();
    hilit('[name = pwd]');
    return false;
  }
  else
  {
  notify('processing.... please wait', 'notice');
  dataString = 'user='+user.value+'&pwd='+pwd.value;
    jQuery.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      data: dataString,
      url: baseurl+'admin/checkLogin', 
      cache: false,
      error: function()
      {
        notify("An error occurd... please try later", 'error');
      },
      success: function(html)
      {
        if(html == 1)
        {
          window.location = baseurl+'admin/home';
        }
        else
        {
          notify('Your login details are incorrect!!!', 'error');
        }
      }
    });
    return false;
  }
  return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are sending the data in a wrong way
The data sent to server must be in key/value pairs. `{key : value}`

modify your data in ajax call like this

```
data : { user : user.value, pwd : pwd.value}
```

**EDIT**

Change your error handling code with this

```
error:function(xhr,err){
    alert("readyState: "+xhr.readyState+"\nstatus: "+xhr.status);
    alert("responseText: "+xhr.responseText);
}
```

Comment: You Means from `dataString = 'user='+user.value+'&pwd='+pwd.value;` to this `data : { user : user.value, pwd : pwd.value}` ?

Comment: no instead if `data: dataString,` put this `data : { user : user.value, pwd : pwd.value},`

Comment: Nopes, its did not work. Showing same error, in new tab the same credentials worked.

Comment: try alerting `user.value` and `pwd.value`

Comment: well, i thought the error was `An error occurd... please try later`, try alerting html that you have returned as an success response if that's not =1 (with your right credentials posted) you might be having some problem in your php return (the response you are returning from php back to ajax call)

Comment: `function checkLogin() {
    $user = $this->input->post('user');
    $pwd = md5($this->input->post('pwd'));
 
    $cnt  = $this->db->count_all("admin where user = '$user' and pwd = '$pwd' ");
 
 
    if($cnt == 1)
    {
      $adminSessionData = array(
        'adminLogdIn' => true,
        'name' => 'Administrator'
      );
      $this->session->set_userdata($adminSessionData);
      echo 1;
    }
    else
    {
      echo 2;
    }
  }`

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/19804/discussion-between-nikita-chopra-and-ravi)